# Immediately Accessing values from Firebase blocks/Avoiding Race Conditions

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, boolean

I have a bool "alreadyHaveProfile" that I change to TRUE inside of a while loop and then I break out of the loop...yet the value of the boolean is still unchanged. Any thoughts?

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
        fetchUserData()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3.5) {
            let dref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("CheckUsers")
            dref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                var alreadyHaveProfile = false
                let enumerator = snapshot.children
                loop: while let user = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                    if user.key == userID {
                        alreadyHaveProfile = true
                        break loop
                    }
                }
            }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            })
            print(alreadyHaveProfile)
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
        fetchUserData()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3.5) {
            let dref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("CheckUsers")
            dref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                var alreadyHaveProfile = false
                let enumerator = snapshot.children
                loop: while let user = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                    if user.key == userID {
                        alreadyHaveProfile = true
                        self.finishSetUp()
                        break loop
                    }
                }
            }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            })
        }

finishSetUp() {
    print(alreadyHaveProfile)
    if !alreadyHaveProfile {
        // finish set up, value of ALREADYHAVEPROFILE is recent and updated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `print(alreadyHaveProfile)` executing before the sync block?

Comment: You can simplify that loop a ton:`alreadyHaveProfile  = snapshot.children.contains(where: { ($0 as? FIRDataSnapshot)?.key == userID`

Comment: @Alexander smooth man, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the state of your variable `alreadyHaveProfile` has not been set yet by the logic that is running inside the loop.  Not having the complete scenario setup in front of me makes it hard to diagnose though.

A couple of things to consider; first it looks like FireBase is performing some database queries to set the state of your variable.  To debug this try and setup a way to watch each iteration of the while loop run and that way you will know if the state of your variable `alreadyHaveProfile` is being set before your print statement is output to the console.

This might help to determine if you are in a race condition or not.

```
        let dref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("CheckUsers")
        dref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var alreadyHaveProfile = false
            var index = 0
            if let userObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects {
                for user in userObjects {
                    if user.key == userID {
                        alreadHaveProfile = true
                    }
                    index += 1
                    print("Value: \(alreadHaveProfile) at index: \(index) in count: \(userObjects.count)")

                    if index == userObjects.count {
                        print("Loop has completed: with value of: \(alreadHaveProfile)")
                    }
                }
            }

        }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        })
        print("Setting initial value: \(alreadyHaveProfile)")
```

The second thing to consider is that possible the user.key and the userID do not match at all and the `alreadyHaveProfile` value is being properly set. To debug this, set some breakpoints inside the loop to see `user.key` and `userID` in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You got it man...it is a race condition. My value changes to TRUE after the print statement outside the loop has executed. What would be my best option then to access the updated boolean value immediately after the query has been performed?

Comment: Glad I could help!  I would say that if the observeSingleEvent() method has a completion block to the closure, that would be a great place to start.  Otherwise you could also access the value of `alreadHaveProfile` by checking to see if the loop has completed.  `if index == userObjects.count { print("Completed loop with value: \(alreadHaveProfile)")  }`

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I removed it from my answer.  The better option for sure is to look to see if a completion block is available.  The routine I provided will work as a temporary solution.  You could also look into dispatch groups as an option to synchronously execute logic.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Was able to come up with a pretty simple fix

Comment: Absolutely!  Glad we were able to work together to find a resolution for you!

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase method `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` is asynchronous. That is, the method returns before the callback runs.

If you add print statements to your code as I have done here, I think you will see that the `print` statement that appears second in the code, is the first one to appear in the Xcode console.

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
    fetchUserData()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3.5) {
        let dref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("CheckUsers")
        dref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var alreadyHaveProfile = false
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            loop: while let user = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                if user.key == userID {
                    alreadyHaveProfile = true
print("1: \(alreadyHaveProfile)")
                    break loop
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        })
print("2: \(alreadyHaveProfile)")
```

Comment: Thanks for that useful bit of info! I have another IF block that checks the value of ALREADYHAVEPROFILE right after the second print statement above...is there any way to access the updated value then? Since I would have to wait until the observeSingleEvent block has run in order to receive the updated TRUE value of alreadyHaveProfile.

Answer (score 0):

Acess **alreadyHaveProfile** variable inside async block.

Below is code for that:

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
        fetchUserData()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3.5) {
            let dref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("CheckUsers")
            dref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                var alreadyHaveProfile = false
                let enumerator = snapshot.children
                loop: while let user = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                    if user.key == userID {
                        alreadyHaveProfile = true
                        print(alreadyHaveProfile)
                        break loop
                    }
                }
            }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            })
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question...sorry